# Can't get the src.zip for jdk-17

Tags: java

I downloaded the jdk-17 from below link: https://download.oracle.com/java/17/latest/jdk-17_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz

But I can't find the src.zip in the jdk folder, which should contain source code. From where can I download that?

Comment: It's in the `lib` subfolder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want：[jdk-17](https://github.com/zxiaofan/JDK/tree/master/jdk-17/src)

---

UPDATE  ：

1. Download '[oracle linux jdk](https://download.oracle.com/java/17/latest/jdk-17_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz)', and you can find `src.zip` via path `jdk-17_linux-x64_bin\jdk-17.0.2\lib\src.zip` ;
2. This link [jdk-17](https://github.com/zxiaofan/JDK/tree/master/jdk-17/src) stores the decompressed files of `src.zip`. Since it's not officially certified, we'd better ignore it even if it's official source code.

Comment: Why would the OP want a link to some random user's Github (supposed) copy of the OpenJDK source?  When the authoritative OpenJDK source is readily available?

Comment: Why don't you link to https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17u?  That is the Official OpenJDK github mirror for JDK 17u.  And there are lots of other versions there too.  But frankly, this question is off-topic anyway.

Comment: My answer is indeed inaccurate, your answer comment is a great addition.